# eclipse jdt import project from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse JDT and was wondering is there any way to import projects from command line. For eclipse CDT, the headless build application serves the purpose but I am not able to do it for eclipse JDT.

I also studied some Stack Overflow posts and came with below link. The solution suggested here is not working and hence requesting my concern here. Please let me know if anyone has any solutions?

[Automate import of Java (Android) projects into Eclipse workspace through commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302297/automate-import-of-java-android-projects-into-eclipse-workspace-through-comman?answertab=active#tab-top)

Thanks

Comment: There hasn't been any change since that answer was written.

Comment: Yes and seems like the solution there does not work. Do you have any insights?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? I haven't tried this but it looks reasonable.

Comment: does not work means the solution given is not complete either or there is some issue in the code. anyways, i have figured out a way now and definitely the instructions and the process on the link is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

So, after long term digging and trying multiple times, I have find a solution for JDT. Anyone, who is facing the same issue can follow the below instructions:

1. Download the jar from the given link: https://github.com/seeq12/eclipse-import-projects-plugin/tree/master/jar
2. Place the above jar in the plugins directory of your installed eclipse. The path to that for Mac OS is: Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins

   For windows the path will be, eclipse > plugins directory
3. Edit the below file:
   For Mac:
   "Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info"

   For Windows:
   "C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info"
4. add jar info, you can copy below line and directly paste to bundles.info file:

   "com.seeq.eclipse.importprojects,1.4.0, 
   plugins/com.seeq.eclipse.importprojects_1.4.0.jar,4,false"
5. after all the above steps, 
   For Mac: go to MacOs directory and run below command

./eclipse -nosplash -application com.seeq.eclipse.importprojects.headlessimport -data  -import

For Windows: go to eclipse directory and run below command:
eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application com.seeq.eclipse.importprojects.headlessimport -data  -import

Please let me know if anyone still faces issues.